# Laravel 5 error SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

Sometimes (about every 20 request) I get this error. But the next (next second), the same request, is fine. I dont know why it failed the first one. Sometimes i can get another error :

> No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

My `.env` database parameters are fine.

I have generated a key using `php artisan key:generate`

This key is in my `.env` file under a `APP_KEY` key

My `config/app.php` has a key `'key' => env('APP_KEY'), 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC'`

does anyone have ANY idea how this can happen?

Comment: Have you checked the length of your key against what the cypher you use requires

Comment: @RiggsFolly, The key is auto generated.  And for some reason sometimes it doesnt work   **APP_KEY=base64:Nr5I9au93AaFua7INh5hqMbafD2JLiKeod7JkYroIo0=**

Comment: i tried to change the code and cut it to 32 characters, but i had the same issues. **APP_KEY=Nr5I9au93AaFua7INh5hqMbafD2JLiKe**

Comment: I've had the same issue and it turned out to be related to threads, see here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24510#issuecomment-395865724

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had this exact same problem for the past few days and I think I solved it:

The settings in .env are not always used for some reason or other and occasionally Laravel will just use the default settings in config/app.php and config/database.php.

config/app.php:

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),

'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

Change the 'SomeRandomString' to the generated key from your .env

config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Change localhost, database, username, password to your actual settings from the .env. This example is for MySQL if you use another database, change those variables instead.

There might be a better solution (more secure?) but this is what so far kept the error from showing up.

Comment: Yeah, i did the same and it is working. But i dont understand why sometimes it skipp my settings

Comment: This needs further investigation. There is some type of bug that causes the .env to be ignored

Comment: This could pose a security risk if you are committing your code to a public repository. By default, the `.env` file is set to be ignored by git for this purpose. I would advise against adding your sensitive details to any of your `config/` files.

Comment: I just change the database.php settings as it is .evn and its work.

Comment: It's too late but might help.  make sure the .env file has been placed in the right location, sometimes it happens that we miss the DOT before the file name as I did.

Comment: Downvoting this because of the security issue it may impose as suggested by @ChuksAdirije

Comment: @ChanYungKeat There isn't really any security issue here, this file shouldn't be accessible on your website and if you commit credentials to a public repository then that's an issue in and of itself (you can likewise commit .env files or the cached file). Granted caching the config file is better but I was not aware of that solution 5+ years ago.

Answer (score 27):

Just cache your config using

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Don't forget to do this every time after setting your  `.env` file.

Comment: what does  this do

Comment: @JaneDoe as the command name suggests, it compiles all configuration files that you have inside your `config` folder, and put it inside `bootstrap/cache/config.php` so that Laravel can use that to retrieve your configurations. When this file exists, Laravel will always get configuration from this file. This improve performance as laravel does not need to guess your file and looks in the config file. To understand deeper on how it works, you can read: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bc4f436b91ef1fae8884ed517f1c3abb6f4d2bb6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php#L20

Comment: And how does this fix the problem?

Comment: @PeterKionga-Kamau To understand how does this fix the problem, we must understand what is the root issue first. Ideally, without the cached file, Laravel will have to guess and look into the config file, and then look into your .env file. However, it is not always the case that Laravel can locate and parse the .env file correctly (I am not sure why but I guess it is due to race condition, does anyone know?). By having the cached file, Laravel will only read from the cached file, avoiding the needs to locate and parse the .env file, hence solving the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I just experienced this after merging in changes from git without updating the `.env` file.

Basically, the person changed the code so that the application required these keys in the env file:

```
DB_SOME_DATABASE=something
DB_SOME_USERNAME=something
DB_SOME_PASSWORD=something
```

But I still had the old credentials in there, so it "looked correct", but Laravel was throwing this error that made it look like the env file wasn't being used.

This would indicate that, if you see this, check very closely if anything is spelled wrong in your `.env` file that would cause Laravel to attempt to use the default values (ie: look in the folder `config/database.php` where you see `'forge'`).

It may not be a typo. Someone may have added a database connection and maybe you haven't updated your `.env` file yet.

Answer (score 2):

You have to delete `bootstrap/cache/config.php`

Comment: would be good to explain the reasoning on why it should be deleted.

Comment: Because there lots of cache file is gathered. So, when you delete it al cache has been cleared.