# Post request and htaccess

Tags: php, angular, laravel, .htaccess, web-hosting

I have a problem with POST request on my hosting. On my hosting server I have domain. We can assume it is:  http://example.com

There are two application: Angular 6 as a frontend and laravel 5.6 as a backend. In public_html folder there is builded angular application but in subfolder /api I have placed laravel rest API application.

There is .httaccess file which should redirect /api/* requests to public.html of laravel app. It looks like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Wstep wzbroniony"
AuthUserFile /home/Smartap/domains/smartap.usermd.net/public_html/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/
RewriteRule (.*) /api/apeczka/public/index.php [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

It works properly when I past in browser link: **http://example.com api/test**

I obtain test data from rest route from API. But the problem is when angular application send POST request to API in order to login user for example. It dosen't work. I obtain:

```
{
    "message": "Server Error"
}
```

from laravel backend. How should I setting that proberly? On localhost everything work well, by there I have two diffrent servers: localhost:4200 - for angular, localhost:8004 - for laravel.

EDITED: 
In server logs I've found something like that:

```
[2018-12-01 20:18:13] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at /usr/home/Smartap/domains/smartap.usermd.net/public_html/api/apeczka/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:50, PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at /usr/home/Smartap/domains/smartap.usermd.net/public_html/api/apeczka/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:46)
    [stacktrace]
```

I would be greateful for help.

Best regards.

Comment: That error in JSON format looks like it's coming from your Laravel API, so your .htaccess is doing its job just fine. You need to check your server's error logs for any PHP errors that will explain why Laravel is giving a server error.

Comment: Thank you I've pasted logs from laravel. Could you look at them?

Comment: Does this maybe help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42261922

Comment: OK, the problem has been solved. I didn't have .env file on server. I don't know why ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in your mysql setup.

Have a look here and make sure that you have configured the connection details correctly.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database

Also make sure that you have cleared your config cache with `php artisan config:clear`

If that throughs the same error then create a file called 'down' in storage/framework and run it again. Once that works run `php artisan up` to start Laravel up again.

Hope that helps.