# how to solve this problem when i enter php artisan project:install

Tags: php, laravel-5

Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied fo
r user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

at C:\wamp64\www\Dashboard_Matbokh\matbokh\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\D
BAL\Driver\PDO\Exception.php:18
14| final class Exception extends PDOException
15| {
16|     public static function new(\PDOException $exception): self
17|     {

> 18|         return new self($exception);
> 19|     }
> 20| }
> 21|

Comment: Please, first have some idea to draw other's attention , [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: This is a similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148086/laravel-5-error-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-forgelocalhost